# Ajax delete method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

hi i try to delete with ajax but my code doesn't work i try many method without results, this is my link:  `

```
<div class="card-btn">
  <%= link_to "Annuler", booking_path(booking), method: :delete, data: { 
  confirm: "Are your sure to delete this booking ?"}, remote: true, class: 
  "btn-delete" %>
</div>`
```

my controller:

```
   def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to profile_path }
    end

  end
```

and my js:

```
$('[data-booking-id=<%= @booking.id %>]').hide();
```

my booking are delete but without animation. i don't see why. 
if someone know i appreciate a help.

Comment: Check out the response in chrome developer tools (network -> request -> response) and see what the js is.  Try it in console to see why it's not working.  Just sounds like a small js bug.

Comment: i read again my code and i don't added data-booking-id=<%= booking. %> in my iteration.

Answer (score 0):

i added data-booking-id in my iteration and now is working.

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" data-booking-id="<%= booking.id %>">
     [...]
  </div>
<% end %>
```